# List of npm registry

Tags: npm

I want list of npm registries. I cannot install npm packages from https://registry.npmjs.org/, registry http://r.cnpmjs.org, http://registry.npmjs.eu, https://registry.npm.taobao.org/. They are all blocked. If you have any idea please make me aware of how can i install packages

Answer (score 1):

Why its blocked?
maybe the right solution will be to use proxy like that (use your proxy its just an example)

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.com:8000
```

or

```
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.com:8000
```

Comment: It does not work. I want a list of registries. Because we cannot reach to npm server. it is blocked by our providers. I want to find different way

Comment: It does not work. I want a list of registries. Because we cannot reach to npm server. it is blocked by our providers. I want to find different way